# Adobe acrobat javascript fetch IP-Adress

Tags: javascript, api, printing, adobe, acrobat-sdk

is it possible and if so, how? To fetch an IP-Adress from withing adobe acrobat javascript?

Best wishes many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found loads of examples in the Adobe Acrobat documentation.
E.g. Net.HTTP.request...